# NullPointerException when creating SpecificDatumWriter<T>

Tags: java, serialization, avro

While learning Apache Avro by Tom White's book, Hadoop: The Definitive Guide, I got an error.

The example has 3 steps:

1. Create an Avro schema file (`Pair.avsc`)

   ```
   {
      "type":"record",
      "name":"Pair",
      "doc":"A pair of strings.",
      "fields":[
         { "name":"left", "type":"string" },
         { "name":"right", "type":"string" }
      ]
   }
   ```
2. Compile the schema file to create a Java class (`Pair.java`) using

   `$ java -jar $AVRO_HOME/avro-tools-1.6.2.jar compile schema src/main/resources/Pair.avsc src/main/java/`
3. Use `SpecificDatumWriter<Pair>` and `SpecificDatumReader<Pair>` to serialize/deserialize data.

The original example method is `testPairSpecific()` in https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/blob/master/avro/src/main/java/AvroTest.java .

I rewrote the example code (`createPairAndSerializeThenDeserialize()` in https://github.com/philipjkim/avro-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/org/sooo/AvroTest.java), which is almost similar to the original one. The differneces are:

1. Avro version I used is 1.6.2, in original 1.3.2.
2. The contents of `Pair.java` created by avro-tools.jar differ (original: https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/blob/master/avro/src/main/java/Pair.java , mine: https://github.com/philipjkim/avro-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sooo/Pair.java )

After running the test, I got an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.String.replace(String.java:2228)
at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.createSchema(SpecificData.java:195)
at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.getSchema(SpecificData.java:140)
at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.<init>(SpecificDatumWriter.java:33)
at org.sooo.AvroTest.createPairAndSerializeThenDeserialize(AvroTest.java:86)
    ...
```

`AvroTest.createPairAndSerializeThenDeserialize()` is:

```
@Test
public void createPairAndSerializeThenDeserialize() throws IOException {
    // given
    Pair datum = new Pair();
    datum.setLeft(new Utf8("L"));
    datum.setRight(new Utf8("R"));

    // serialize
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DatumWriter<Pair> writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<Pair>(Pair.class); /* Line 86 */
    Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(out, null);
    writer.write(datum, encoder);
    encoder.flush();
    out.close();

    // deserialize
    DatumReader<Pair> reader = new SpecificDatumReader<Pair>(Pair.class);
    Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(out.toByteArray(),
    null);
    Pair result = reader.read(null, decoder);

    // then
    assertThat(result.getLeft().toString(), is("L"));
    assertThat(result.getRight().toString(), is("R"));
}
```

I'd like to know what is wrong with this example. Thanks for any comments.

FYI, my example project repo is https://github.com/philipjkim/avro-examples .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Pair.avsc` file is missing a namespace field for your custom package name:

```
...
  "namespace": "org.sooo",
...
```